# Screen turns on after closing lid

Tags: macbook-pro, macos, sleep-wake

Hi please I have problem with my MacBook going into sleep mode after I close lid. The screen turns off, but after few seconds it turns on again (apple logo starts glowing) and tikes additional few seconds before it goes to sleep..When I open the lid again when the apple logo is glowing, there is just only black screen with cursor until it goes to sleep.

Comment: Do you have any devices such as USB mice or keyboards attached? Any external hard disk drive or monitors attached?

Comment: No..I also turned of sharing,as well as apache,remote login, bluetooth sharing.
It acutally sleeps ok, but it takes longer then usually (I guess) and there is the glowing apple problem (that has not been before)

Comment: Does the Apple logo continue to glow with the lid down? This suggests the display is still powered on. Use "pmset -g log" in Terminal.app and look for possible unexpected wake or error messages.